# drupal 7 ajax dependent dropdown

Tags: ajax, dropdown

I have created a custom html form that is having 2 dropdowns State and City. When selects a State i want to populate the city dropdown. But the feature is not working. I already followed many urls but unable to solve the issue.

See the code below i have tried. Can anybody help me.

function zenuineform($form, &$form_state) {

```
$value_dropdown_first = isset($form_state['values']['comp_state']) ? $form_state['values']['comp_state'] : 1;

$form = array();

 $form['comp_state']=array(
    '#type'=>'select',
    '#title'=>t('State : '),
    '#options'=> $state_arr,
    '#default_value' => $state,
    '#ajax' => array(
        // When 'event' occurs, Drupal will perform an ajax request in the
        // background. Usually the default value is sufficient (eg. change for
        // select elements), but valid values include any jQuery event,
        // most notably 'mousedown', 'blur', and 'submit'.
        'event' => 'change',
        'callback' => 'zenuineform_ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'filtered_city',
    ),
  );

$form['comp_city']=array(
    '#type'=>'select',
    '#title'=>t('City : '),
    '#default_value' => $city, 
    '#prefix' => '<div id="filtered_city">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
     '#options' => zenuineform_second_dropdown_options($value_dropdown_first),

  );

  return $form;
```

}

function zenuineform_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {

```
return $form['comp_city'];
```

}
function zenuineform_second_dropdown_options($state_id = '') {

```
if($state_id !='' ) {
    $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM zen_city WHERE state_id = '.$state_id);

    if ($result) {
        $options = '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
        while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {

            $rows[$row['id']] = $row['city_name'];

        }

        return $rows;            
    }
}    
else {
    return array('--Select--');
}
```

}